# Export rendered JSX(html) in plain html and print in the console as well as export as .html file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am working on drag n drop editor using drag n drop feature,  rendering HTML based on state object now I wanted to grab rendered HTML from #editor div and pass the plain HTML code in API and print in the console.